# Prove or disprove $f_{xy}(0,0)=f_{yx}(0,0)$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Prove or disprove $f_{xy}(0,0)=f_{yx}(0,0)$, where
> $$ f(x,y) =
> \begin{cases}
> xy,  & \text{if $|y|≤|x|$} \\
> -xy, & \text{if $|y|>|x|$}
> \end{cases}$$

MY ATTEMPT:
$$f_x=
\begin{cases}
y,  & \text{if $|y|≤|x|$} \\
-y, & \text{if $|y|>|x|$}
\end{cases}$$
Similarly,
$$f_y=
\begin{cases}
x,  & \text{if $|y|≤|x|$} \\
-x, & \text{if $|y|>|x|$}
\end{cases}$$
Then
\begin{equation}
f_{xy}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f_y(h,0)-f_y(0,0)}{h}=0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
f_{yx}=\lim_{k\to 0}\frac{f_x(0,k)-f_x(0,0)}{k}=0
\end{equation}
hence $f_{xy}(0,0)=f_{yx}(0,0)$.
Similarly, we go for $|y|>|x|$.

Is this approach is correct? Please clarify, and if not then please provide the correct path. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that $f_x$ and $f_y$ are calculated correctly ?

Answer (score 1):

You should have
$$f_x(x,y)=\begin{cases}
y,  & \text{if $|y|<|x|$} \\
-y, & \text{if $|y|>|x|$}
\end{cases}
\quad\text{and}\quad 
f_y(x,y)=\begin{cases}
x,  & \text{if $|y|<|x|$} \\
-x, & \text{if $|y|>|x|$}
\end{cases}$$
Along the lines $y=x$ and $y=-x$ with the exception of the origin, $f$ is not derivable. As regards $(0,0)$, since $f(t,0)=f(0,t)=0$ for any real $t$, then $f_x(0,0)=f_y(0,0)=0$.

Hence, according to the [usual notations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative#Notation),
$$f_{xy}(0,0)=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f_x(0,t)-f_x(0,0)}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{-t-0}{t}= -1$$
and
$$f_{yx}(0,0)=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f_y(t,0)-f_y(0,0)}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{t-0}{t}= 1.$$